# Medieval political hierarchy with an elite 4 counsel elected based on score points - Part 3

Tags: magic, medieval, nanotechnology

Question's [part one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85901/medieval-political-hierarchy-with-an-elite-4-counsel-elected-based-on-score-poin) and [part two](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85925/medieval-political-hierarchy-with-an-elite-4-counsel-elected-based-on-score-poin)

---

To sum everything up :

My society is Medieval-like and **led by a counsel of 4 people named the Elite 4.** Each member of the Elite 4 represents one of the 4 classes (Inquisitors, Scholars, Workers, Soldiers) and gets his/her sit **based on a score point.**

**Citizens vote** during elections are part of this score point and the other part is based on **points awarded for good deeds or subtracted for unlawful actions.** (example : winning a duel, arresting a proven heretic, discovering a new breed, murder)

Any member of the Elite 4 can be subject to a popular vote to kick him/her out of the counsel if enough people of his/her class decide he/she is no longer fit to represent them.

The 5th class called **Judges do not take part in the Elite 4.** However they posses a book storing the point value for most common actions and **their job is to keep track of the point accumulation of each citizen** as well as deciding how they should fluctuate the point values in specific situations.

The Judges are never to leave their keep so that they may not be swayed by other classes. **They receive reports filled by citizens of the deeds they have accomplished** and by the Inquisitor of the criminals they have arrested and change the score points accordingly.

The difference with my precedent iteration of the Judges' concept is that they no longer have the sightstone to see for themselves. I want to introduce **a "mafia" in the faction that would trade others' deeds for money.**

Score points only matters for your political status and do not change your social standings. No money or services are provided for higher score point. One only gets greater political influence out of it. Therefore, people not interested in politics will seek to exchange those for money hence the mafia.

The mafia uses the political power obtained to influence decisions in favor of their legal businesses.

In order to do so, **I need to grant the Judges a power that would make it so only the person who actually accomplished the deed may fill the report** BUT **it could be traded anyway you see fit**. Therefore, the mafia cannot simply use falsification and has to trade ACTUAL deeds.

---

How do I make it so Judges will know if a report is faux or not for sure but will award points to whoever name is written?

---

- Medieval-like : By "Medieval" I meant a society where religion still has a strong political power. Farmers work the field for a lord (Veteran soldier or Inquisitor. Scholars are fed by the tax on the lords' harvests to the Curatorium) or in the machine rooms/labs for the scholars.

Deed trading has to be illegal.

You may give the Judges a stone power but its effect has to be explained by nanotechnology.

You may replace the report system.

Comment: I'm not saying your question is incomprehensible, but certainly confusing. I had to read it 5 times. You do not seem to understand certain things (medieval, judicature, subjectivism, class systems, nanotechnology ...) and use those concepts unconventionally. There are also subtle, distracting Roman influences here. This is ok, they can be anything you want in your world, but it makes it hard to understand what you want. Maybe you could rethink your structure and cut all the unimportant details? Also I think you are asking how to construct a perfect society - you can't

Comment: It got kind of confusing I can understand that. This is my first time doing this and I went on some complicated stuff right of the bat so that doesn't help. What do you consider unimportant details ? A perfect society is what I wanted at first but it is not as interesting as many pointed out so I shifted away from that.

Comment: I cannot tell you what the unimportant details are. If I knew, the question would be easier to understand. Take just for example, I could've taken almost anything else: "Score points only matters for your political status and do not change your social standings. (No money or services are provided for higher score point. One only gets greater political influence out of it)". Does this have anything to do with your question? I do not know. Also asking how someone cannot possibly be fooled to me sounds like asking for a perfect society. I think you should also reformulate that

Comment: "Score points only matters for your political status and do not change your social standings. (No money or services are provided for higher score point. One only gets greater political influence out of it)" This is the reason people go to the mafia to sell their deeds. They have no interest in politics and will exchange it for money. I said "cannot by false reports", they can be fooled but not just by creating false reports is what I meant

Comment: I already understand this a bit better. I know the problem. I often write answers/comments and a day later when reading through them, I do not have any idea what I am talking about. Apparently some people are not as stupid as me and already understood the question, but if I were you I'd rework some parts

Comment: Doing it as we speak ^^ Thanks for the insightful critics

Comment: Each registered citizen is given a privately held, registered and secret insignia that the Judges hold the only records to. It's printed on a sealed section of the report with invisible ink, so only the judges will see it (or they will know it's been opened). Technically, someone COULD put their invisible insignia on a blank report, but doing so is risky, since someone could write anything they wanted. Might be a mafia vehicle for "insurance," though...

Comment: The mafia would just steal those insignia or force you to use them. I'm really trying to force them into being more of a black market rather than just a violent thief organization

Comment: A society in which religious organizations hold considerable power would not allow voting unless for appearances only...see history of the Earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your previous descriptions, I think a slightly faulty use if magic stone would do. Just use it as a lie detector. It should be able to tell if the person submitting the report actually believes what's in that record.

It would require the report to be put there in person for this to work. Person could state "this report is honest" and stone turns green. Now, imagine person saying "I did what is described here". It is true. Stone is green. Judge has hundreds more reports to accept today. He can't know the name of each person in the city. So he accepts the report, all right. And later there is only a name on paper, and deed description. Exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Playing on words to bypass the lie detection. I like it

Comment: I'm at work so I can't provide a full answer, but this reminds me of The Unincorporated Man by Dani and Eytan Kollin. Their "point system" was handled by a stock market, though. For your idea, one question I have is:  do the judges deal with EVERYONE's points or just those above a certain threshhold?  If everyone, their job goes from interesting to mostly mere drudgery. I recommend having a bureaucracy deal with the minor cases, with all the accompanying intrigue.